# Small admin control panel code on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to develop a small control panel for admin to distribute roles to other users, the thing is my code doesn't show me any error but at the same time it doesn't affect any roles to other users. it stays just the same way,
my control panel is based on submit methode automatically hen i check the role for a specific user.

my view admin code that contains control panel is;

```
      <div class="row offset-2">

           <div class="col-md-4 course_box">


   <h4>Panel de Controle </h4><br>
   <h6> <b>Liste des utilisateurs :</b></h6>
    <br><br>
   <div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Elève</th>
            <th>Enseignant</th>   
            <th>Parent</th>   
            <th>Administrateur</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($users as $user)
             <form method="post" action="/add-role">

           {{ csrf_field() }}


           <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
            <tr>
                  <th>{{ $user->id }}</th>
                  <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                   <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type= "checkbox" name='role_elève' onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ $user->hasRole('Elève') ? 'checked' : ' ' }}>  </td>
                     <td> <input type= "checkbox" name='role_ens' onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ $user->hasRole('Enseignant') ? 'checked' : ' ' }}></td>
                      <td> <input type= "checkbox" name='role_parent'  onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ $user->hasRole('Parent') ? 'checked' : ' ' }}></td>
                       <td> <input type= "checkbox" name='role_admin'  onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ $user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : ' ' }}></td>
                   </tr>
               </form>
                   @endforeach
                   </table>
                   </div>

          </div></div>
```

web.php contains the route add-role below:

```
  Route::post('add-role', [ 
  'uses' => 'PostsController@addRole',
   'as' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
      'roles' => ['Admin']
   ]);
```

addRole method in PostsController implements the code below:

```
   Public function addRole(Request $request) {

        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();
        $user->roles()->detach();

      if($request['role_elève'])
      {
         $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Elève')->first());

      }

       if($request['role_ens'])
      {
         $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Enseignant')->first());

      }

       if($request['role_parent'])
      {
         $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Parent')->first());

      }

    if($request['role_admin'])
      {
         $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first());

      }

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I can't find the error when laravel doesn"t detect the details of it, any help would be appreciated alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$request` is object, not array...

Therefore, to make it work, change all your `$request[` declarations to `$request->` in your PostController, like in this example:

```
public function addRole(Request $request) {

$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
$user->roles()->detach();

if($request->role_elève) {
    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Elève')->first());
}

if($request->role_ens) {
   $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Enseignant')->first());
}

if($request->role_parent) {
   $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Parent')->first());
}

if($request->role_admin) {
   $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first());
}

return redirect()->back();
}
```

Note:

I would suggest also, to change variable name of `role_elève` to `role_eleve`. If so, remember to modify fields in your view accordingly...

Comment: Hi Bart, Thank you for your comment, I changed exactly what you told me to change, it's still the same thing, no errors detected by laravel as there is no role distribution made by admin and the table of control panel remains the same :/ any other suggestion??

Comment: Are you sure your requests are reaching your addRole function in the first place? Please post result of `dd($request);` placed next line after `public function addRole(Request $request) {` in your controller...

Comment: Hello Bart, I don't think my request reaches addRole function in PostsController, as far as i can see  whenever I check the role box it doesn't redirect me to the same view or any other view, no changes seem to be applied, how can i fix this?

Comment: you mean in this part of my view code: <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}"> and change {{ $user->email }} to 1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, like for an example you mean this:      <input type= "checkbox" name='role_eleve' onChange="this.form.submit()" value='1' {{ $user->hasRole('Elève') ? 'checked' : ' ' }}>  </td>      ??

Comment: Yes I did, but no results appeared to see, nothing changed

Comment: @EkramQueen I suppose not, cause you would see this error immediately...

Comment: @EkramQueen you can use Postman to verify your routes... And for the rest, my best bet, is that your html is not properly formatted. Use your browser console to find errors...

Comment: thank you Bart, my admin panel finally works, I appreciate your help, Goodluck!

Comment: @EkramQueen happy to hear.